# 'rails generate controller' doesn't create any files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The command succeeds in running, and says that the files are created, however there are no files created, and running the command again says that they already exist.

after `rails generate controller`, at `~/Desktop/Projects/RailsTutorial`:

```
  create  app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/static_pages
  invoke  test_unit
  create    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/static_pages_helper.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/static_pages.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.scss
```

`ls` at `~/Desktop/Projects/RailsTutorial/app/controllers`:

```
  application_controller.rb  concerns
```

Comment: When you say files,which files you are referring to?

Comment: Can you provide the full command you're entering? Have you perhaps added the `-p` option?

Comment: The command which automatically generates views is scaffold i.e rails g scaffold_controller controller_name this will generate CRUD views for you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a methode after the name of the controller? To have an erb view file and route in the config/routes.rb, you need to create a methode with controller too.

```
bundle exec rails g controller Recipes index

create  app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb
       route  get 'recipes/index'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/recipes
      create    app/views/recipes/index.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/recipes_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/recipes_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/recipes.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/recipes.scss
```